# How to use profile2 profile type in custom form?

Tags: forms

I'm building a multi step sign up form for my drupal 7 website, so I want to use one of profile type from profile2 in first step.
For such purpose I'm using this code:

```
function personal_info_form($form, $form_state) {
    $form_state['profiles']['main'] = profile2_get_types('main');
    profile2_attach_form($form, $form_state);
    $form['#validate'][] = 'profile2_form_validate_handler';
    $form['#submit'][] = array('profile2_form_submit_build_profile', 'profile2_form_submit_handler');
    return $form;
}
```

But still getting error, you can visit this page to see the exact error
http://dev.BlindHelp.net/user/register . Any help?

Answer (score 0):

i Suggest to use hook_form_alter or hook_FORM_ID_form_alter to perform specific task of existing form of profile2.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)  {
    switch ($form_id)  {
        case 'comment_form_id':
            $form['your_comment_form_name'] = array (
              '#type' => 'checkbox',
              '#title' => t ('Subscribe to replies to this comment'),
            );
            break;
        case 'user_register_form' :
           $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Submit');
           break;
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you give me an example? how can I go through out?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens can you please give me an example according to my code?

Comment: i have edited my answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.       I need some more help if you can do ? I'm basically building a multi step sign up form for my drupal 7 website. can you help me in that? we are following this guide to build our custom module. but we got stuck to alter the user_register_form, we are not able to remove the create account button in any way, I can sho you my code if you want ..      http://matthewgrasmick.com/posts/building-multistep-registration-form-drupal-7

Comment: i have edited my answer. this will work fine

Comment: Thank You so much @Abhishek singh, I want to talk to you, I don't know maybe this would be a rule braking, so sorry for that. but Would like to discuss something with you, so Abhishek can you allow me to contact you personally?